# Ограничение диапазона чисел в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется функция, которая обрабатывает инпут и ограничивает его в диапазоне от 1 до 1000. Но не срабатывает ограничение на ввод только цифр, помогите разобраться.

```
 onChangeSearch(e) {
    let regexp = [0-9];
    let value = e.target.value;
    value = value.replace(regexp, '').substr(0, 4);
    this.setState({
        filter_search: value
    });

    if (value <= 0) {
        this.setState({
            filter_search: value = 1
        });
    } else if (value >= 1000) {
        this.setState({
            filter_search: value = 1000
        });
    }
```

Comment: лучше написать `<input type="number" min="1" max="1000" />`

Comment: Помог тип, но ограничение диапазона почему то не работает, оставил это дело на функцию. Остался вопрос, как убрать срелки инкремента\декремента справа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите это в свойствах элемента `input`:

```html
<input type="number"></input>
```

Comment: От части помогло. Скопирую и сюда "Помог тип, но ограничение диапазона почему то не работает, оставил это дело на функцию. Остался вопрос, как убрать срелки инкремента\декремента справа?"

Comment: @MrYogurt Это делается при помощи css - [ссылка](https://gist.github.com/wilddip/c1d77e92a955045f2480860e02b90339)

Comment: Да, такое решение я и сам нагуглил, просто думал есть менее колхозный способ, но спасибо.

Comment: @MrYogurt это не колхоз, а способ реализации :)